# Is Engine a reserved word in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have a model named Engine, and I am able to use it in views and controllers without issues.
The problem occurs when I use it in a model (for example, in callbacks or even simple instance methods).

```
#inside the vehicle model
def add_engines
  Engine.all.each do |ngin|
  ...

end
```

I get the error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'all' for #<Some_mounted_engine_name:0x00000103b48828>`

I search the web, but I do not see Engine as a reserved word. Note that we use mounted engines in our app.

Comment: I think some gem you are using may have defined class `Engine`. Is it problem only in `Vehicle` model?

Comment: no, any model in the host or main app that wants to reference Engine has the error.

Comment: Can you just open rails console and try `Engine.new`.. what it gives?

Comment: console seems fine...it is only when used inside a model's method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're running into Ruby scoping issues.  Try `::Engine` instead of `Engine` - you're probably implicitly referring to [`Rails::Engine`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html)

Comment: yes, this saved the day. So, to further my understanding, why do the Views and Controllers work, but not Models?

Comment: That's a bit difficult to answer for sure, but somewhere the `Engine` module/class was included into the model's list of included modules (via the superclass most likely).  Tracking down the where is less straightfoward.  To poke around, try looking at `YourModelClass.included_modules` and see what's in scope